# Convert rtf to html, keep colors

Tags: python, html, converters, rtf, file-conversion

I need to convert a bunch of RTF files to HTML keeping the same formatting as possible

So I tried that python script that converts all rtf files from a folder to its html variants:

```py
from glob import glob
import re
import os
import win32com.client as win32
import base64
import mammoth
from win32com.client import constants
from docx import Document
import sys

def change_word_format(file_path):
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(file_path)
    doc.Activate()

    new_file_abs = os.path.abspath(file_path)
    new_file_abs = re.sub(r'\.\w+$', '.docx', new_file_abs)
    
    word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(
        new_file_abs, FileFormat=constants.wdFormatDocumentDefault
    )
    doc.Close(False)
    return new_file_abs

def convert_image(image):
    with image.open() as image_bytes:
        encoded_src = base64.b64encode(image_bytes.read()).decode("ascii")
    return {"src": f"data:{image.content_type};base64,{encoded_src}"}

def convert_docx_to_html(input_docx):    
    with open(input_docx, "rb") as docx_file:
        result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file, convert_image=mammoth.images.img_element(convert_image))
        html = result.value
        
    output_html = os.path.splitext(input_docx)[0] + ".html"
    
    with open(output_html, "w", encoding="utf-8") as html_file:
        html_file.write(html)

    return output_html

def convert_rtf_to_html(input_rtf):
    input_docx = change_word_format(input_rtf)
    output_html = convert_docx_to_html(input_docx)
    os.remove(input_docx)
    return output_html

def convert_rtf_files_to_html(start_path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".rtf"):
                input_rtf = os.path.join(root, file)
                output_html_path = convert_rtf_to_html(input_rtf)
                print(f"Converted {input_rtf} to {output_html_path}")
                os.remove(input_rtf)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_path = sys.argv[1]
    convert_rtf_files_to_html(start_path)
```

I want also to keep text colors from rtf in html actually black